# SMS payment option for website access

Tags: sms

I see this very often in the UK where websites will let you signup by sending a text to a number, I have never seen an option for this in the USA do you know if there are any company's for the small time guys in the US that can provide this service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://google.com/search?q=sms+short+codes+usa

http://www.usshortcodes.com/

http://www.textmarks.com/

etc...

Comment: Wow; a number of recent downvotes. Not sure what's with all the negativity all of a sudden. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Try Zong (Switzerland), or EVP (Lithuania), they both provide US short codes.

In the US, Premium SMS requires double-opt-in, which drastically reduces the conversion rates.

Dan.